# What is the definition of rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How is rotation of geometrical objects defined in mathematics?
For example given a triangle,line or a geometric vector what is a rotation technically?

what is literally the explicit def of rotation. This is my question, wiki talks about some matrix nonsense,. I am not asking about some representation of rotation in a basis or in coordinates, but the actual definition. –

Comment: This question may be too broad. Maybe what you are intrested in are linear operators expressed via matrices which rotate vectors.

Comment: There are several equivalent ways you could define it. Most of the time, the term is not explicitly defined. One way to define a rotation function from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$ is as a surjective (or, equivalently, injective) affine function with a unique fixed point. A rotation of a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ would just be the image of that subset under a rotation map.

Comment: Yeah so what is literally the explicit def of rotation. This is my question, wiki talks about some matrix nonsense,. I am not asking about some representation of rotation in a basis or in coordinates, but the actual definition.

Comment: Theo, ok that is something that makes sense. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Rotation is a distance preserving bijection of the plane with a fixed point

Comment: "some matrix nonsense"... It's not nonsense, it's actual sense. Just because it's not in the form you would like it to be does not make it nonsense.

Comment: @Schaurberger What would you like me to expand on specifically? Do you need me to explain any of the terms? Is there some intuitive notion of rotation that you'd like me to connect this definition to?

Comment: Well rotation can be on a 3d space,than it has a fixed set of points making a line.i don't think rotations are affine. Then they wouldn't have a fixed point would they? I think a more explicit definition would be that it is a subgroup the the orthogonal group , specifically a composition of an even number of reflections( proper maps)

Comment: I specifically mentioned $\Bbb{R}^2$ for this reason. It's difficult to go beyond this because rotations are an inherently two-dimensional notion. That's why, sooner or later, bases are going to have to pop their heads up sooner or later. Also, no an affine function can fix points (although translations do not), e.g. a rotation around a point that is not necessarily the origin. I also should point out that my definition misses the identity map, which is often considered a kind of degenerate rotation.

Answer (score 3):

From *Linear Algebra, 4th Edition*, by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence, Section 6.11.

**Definition.** Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional real inner product space $V$. The operator $T$ is called a **rotation** if and only if $T$ is the identity on $V$, or if there exists a two-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$, an orthonormal basis $\beta=[x_1,x_2]$ for $W$, and a real number $\theta$ such that:
$$\begin{align*}
T(x_1) &= (\cos\theta)x_1 + (\sin\theta)x_2\\
T(x_2) &= (-\sin\theta)x_1 + (\cos\theta)x_2\\
T(y) &= y\quad\text{if }y\in W^{\perp}.
\end{align*}$$

That is, $T$ acts the way we think a "rotation" behaves on the plane on a 2-dimensional subspace, and on the orthogonal complement (the "axis of rotation") acts like the identity.

More generally, a rotation need not be a linear transformation, but it does have to be a rigid motion (preserves ditances). Since one can show that a rigit motion on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal linear operator composed with a translation, this gives you a way of describing a general rotation that is not linear: namely, a rotation will be a function of the form $\tau_{\mathbf{a}}\circ T\circ \tau_{-\mathbf{a}}$, where $T$ is a linear operator that is a rotation in the sense above, and for a point $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\tau_{\mathbf{a}}$ is the "translation by $\mathbf{a}$, $\tau_{\mathbf{a}}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is a distance preserving bijection of the space with a fixed point.

*(It is important to note that a "proper" rotation is one that preserves the orientation of the space.  So it is not a reflection and a rotation, which is really just a reflection)*

Using a more concrete example, consider a unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $A=(0,0),B=(1,0),C=(1,1),D=(0,1)$.
There a few choices for the fixed point, let's say we want to rotate the square around the origin $(0,0)$.
Then we are looking a map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is:

- Injective: For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x\neq y$, then $T(x)\neq T(y)$
- Surjective: For all $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$, there is an $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x)=y$
- Distance Preserving: For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$, if $||x-y||=d$, then $||T(x)-T(y)||=d$
- Fixes the middle of the square: $T( (0,0) ) = (0,0)$

The matrix from wikipedia is an example of such a map

Comment: Your definition would make $T(x,y) = (-x,y)$, a distance preserving bijection of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a fixed point, into a rotation. But it is generally considered a **reflection**, not a rotation.

Comment: You're right, i think the wiki page refers to those as "proper" and "improper" rotations... I will make a note in the answer

Comment: As far as I know a rotation is nothing but a proper orthogonal (linear) transformation , still this is nonsense what you're saying, this is not geography , I thaught positions in mathematics and physics were characterised by vectors not by numbers! ?

Comment: Any element $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ can be seen as a vector, say $x=(x_1 , x_2 )$.  Not sure what you're looking for?

Comment: Geometric vector as noted in the description, that means just a directed line

Answer (score 0):

(a) In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a rotation is an isometry (distance-preserving map ) $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with a unique fixed point, say $C$, and such that the angle $\widehat{M_1CM}$ is a constant, call it $\alpha$,  for every point $M \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{C\}$, where $M_1=f(M)$. The point $C$ is called the center of the rotation and $\alpha$ is the angle of the rotation.

(b) In $\mathbb{R}^3$, a rotation is an isometry (distance-preserving map ) $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ whose set of fixed points is a line, say $L$, and such that for any plane, $P$, perpendicular to $L$, the restriction, $f_{|P}$ of $f$ on $P$ is a rotation in the sense of (a). The center of the rotation $f_{|P}$ is the point of intersection of $L$ and $P$. Furthermore, for every point $M \in \mathbb{}^3-L$, let $C$  be the orthogonal projection of $M$ onto $L$ and $M_1=f(M)$. Then the angle $\widehat{M_1CM}$ is a constant called the angle of the rotation $f$.